# Including Header From Sub-folder Pages Using PHP

Tags: php

I am using PHP includes in order to include header and footer to all site pages. It is working fine unless I am surfing top level pages which are 'index' and 'about' for example. On lower level pages, which are 'product1' and 'product2' includes work but do not grab styles. I can fix the issue by creating additional header and footer includes for internal pages where I will change style links from "styles.css" to "../styles.css" but I would like to find another solution keeping only one header and one footer. Is there a way to do so?

Website Structure

```
-assets
  -includes
     header.html
     footer.html
  +css
  +js
-products
  product1.php
  product2.php
index.php
about.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using root-relative links (e.g. /styles.css) fixes the issue.

More details about link types can be found [here](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php)